# LinkGenerator GetPathByPage returns null for an Area Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to get an absolute URI for an Area Page in razor pages. I am using LinkGenerator's GetUriByPage method. While this works for pages that are not within an Area, it returns null when I am trying to get the URI for an Area Page in my application. Below is an example of what I am doing.

```
var uri = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(HttpContext, "/SomeArea/Tickets/Index", null, new { CurrentFilter = "Open" });
```

What am I missing? I don't see an GetUriByAreaPage method. Is it simply not available to do this?

Answer (score 3):

On https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/areas there is this section:

> If using the RedirectToPage method to transfer someone to a location
> within an area, you should use the overload that takes an object
> representing route values to specify the area:
>
> ```
> public IActionResult OnGet() 
> { 
>     return RedirectToPage("/Create", new { area = "Administration" }); 
> }
> ```

I applied this same logic to GetUriByPage. Below is my previous example, but one that actually works.

```
var uri = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(HttpContext, "/Tickets/Index", null, new { Area = "SomeArea", CurrentFilter = "Open" });
```

Comment: adding */Index* did the trick ... UrlHelper has always happily worked without that :-/